# Schedule to "now" (current time) in date/time prompt (calendar)

Tags: org-mode, calendar, todo, prompt

I would like to be able to insert the current time with a shortcut when I schedule a task.

There is the "." for jumping to the current day (today), but I have not been able to figure out a shortcut to put the current time (now) in the org-schedule input line. I tried putting in "now", but it does not take effect.

The shortcut is useful if I have some Tasks scheduled without time for the day and would like to set them on the agenda time grid. Also when I get a unplanned tasks that I have to do right away this would be useful.

I know there is the `C-u C-u C-c .` command to insert a current timestamp, but it does not work in the date/time prompt.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of such a shortcut. But you can do `C-u C-u C-.` on the scheduled date *after* you enter it the buffer with `org-read-date`.

Comment: Thanks, you inspired me to use template expansion. If I add the line `(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("S" "SCHEDULED: ?"))` to my configuration I can type <S and hit TAB to expand it to SCHEDULED: . Then I can use the (corrected - sorry) shortcut for insert timestamp. It is still kind of cumbersome though.

Comment: ... I think I misunderstood. Could you give an example on how to use `org-read-date`

Comment: When you do `C-c C-s` and you are asked to enter a date, you are using `org-read-date` underneath the covers. IOW, what I suggested is you just enter a SCHEDULED: date without worrying about the time. Aftet that date has been entered into the buffer (either directly or during `org-capture`), then you place the cursor on the date and do `C-u C-u C-c .` to add the time.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @NickD! This way is better than looking the time up and entering it manually. So def. an improvement. I would prefer some equivalent to "." for today, though ;-)

Comment: I understand but as I said I don't know of any (and I did look a bit).

Comment: @NickD After using your solution for some days I like it better, than I thought in the first place. The workflow is easy and saves some hassle. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome! If I find some time, I'll write it up as an answer - or *you* can!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure emacs way, but more of a hack. Still it works pretty good in day to day use:

The software [espanso](https://espanso.org/docs/matches/#date-extension) works on linux, mac and windows and expands keys similar to the package `yasnippet`.

On their documentation there is [an example](https://espanso.org/docs/matches/#date-extension) how to match the current time to `:now`, which solves the problem for me. It worked basically everywhere I needed it for now, also in emacs interactive dialogues. Its good enough until there is a native way.

https://espanso.org/docs/matches/#date-extension